# How can I make my kivy layout the same scale on iPad and iPhone?

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy, scale

I have got my app working on my iPhone at a scale that looks good. I have run it now on my iPad and everything is much more spaced out and the text appears much smaller. I have had the app open on both devices and held them next to each other and it appears as though the text size is actually the same on both. Obviously it looks smaller on a bigger screen.

Another thing that is kind of strange is that on the iPad, the app screen fills the whole screen entirely, but on the iPhone, it kind of runs shy of the top and bottom by about 10% each way.

I have done a fair bit of looking around at apple's stuff and on kivy docs but can't see anything conclusive.

How may I make it so they're are automatically scaled on any iOS device? Also, how can I make the app fill out the whole screen on the iPhone? Is it something in Xcode that needs to be changed, or is it a kivy thing? I am a bit lost here. Any help will be much appreciated thank you.

**EDIT**:
I will include a widget from one of my kivy pages, maybe the problem is in the way i'm laying it out.

```
BoxLayout:
    pos_hint: {"top": .9, "center_x": .5}
    size_hint: 1, .3
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 450 # set 330 for iphone
    ScrollView:
        Label:
            id: brief_res_1
            font_size: '11sp'
            do_scroll_x: True
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: None
            size: self.texture_size
            halign: "left"
            valign: "center"
            text:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `size_hint` and `pos_hint` for widgets in your `kv`, and use the `kivy.metrics` (`sp`) for `font_size`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @John Anderson. I have edited my question to show an example of one of my widgets. Maybe i'm doing it wrong, may you please check? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As of what I know, there's currently no concrete answer to your problem, due to the differences between iPhones' and iPads' screen sizes and ratios. There is, however, 2 solutions that I suggest you trying:

- The `platform` variable from `kivy.utils` stores the name of the platform that it's running on. If I'm correct, if your app is running on an iPhone then it should return `"ios"`, and `"unknown"` for an iPad, because it apparently does not check for `"ipados"`. If it's true, you should make a separated kivy script from your iOS-compatible one that prefers the iPad screen size, and afterwards you can add a check, something like this:

```python
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.lang import Builder

if platform == "ios":
    Builder.load_file("ios.kv")
elif platform == "unknown":
    Builder.load_file("ipados.kv")
else:
    # your preferences...
```

- If for whatever reason `platform` returns `"ios"` on an iPad, then I say you should get the screen resolution first, and then do a check similar to the above example, something like this:

```python
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.fullscreen = True
Window.maximize()

resolution = Window.size
Window.fullscreen = False

if resolution[0] / resolution[1] < 1:
    Builder.load_file("ios.kv")
else:
    Builder.load_file("ipados.kv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I will certainly give this a go. I was thinking maybe i'd need to do something like this but was just hopeful for an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

To fill out the whole screen, you can check the checkbox “Requires fullsceeen” in Xcode’s general page. After that, run your app and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).